# jQuery: margin animation works in Chrome, not in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Project: http://design.vitalbmx.com/fave/news.html

When I click "Add to favorites" button (under main pic), in Chrome it animates UL,
while in Firefox and IE it does not work.

Can't figure out why it works differently. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox won't animate `margin-left` correctly.  Instead make your `<ul>` relatively positioned and use the `left` attribute.

So instead of `margin-left: -125px;` use  `left: -125px; position: relative;`

And change your animation to:

```
$j('#fave_recent ul').animate({'left': 0}, 500);
```

This will work across all browsers.